# Ternary operator within Java Streams

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I have the following function which utilizes streams and collectors to create a map and differs in execution based on a boolean input parameter `isMultiSelectableQuiz`:

```
private Map<Integer, Long> getCountPerAnswerChoice(boolean isMultiSelectableQuiz, int questionId, List<QuizResponse> quizResponses) {
     return isMultiSelectableQuiz
        ? quizResponses.stream()
            .flatMap(response -> response.getAnswersByQuestions().stream())
            .filter(answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getQuestionId() == questionId)
            .collect(
                Collectors.flatMapping(
                    (QuizQuestionAnswer answerByQuestion) -> answerByQuestion.getAnswerSelectionsList().stream(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(selection -> selection, Collectors.counting())))
        : quizResponses.stream()
            .flatMap(response -> response.getAnswersByQuestions().stream())
            .filter(answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getQuestionId() == questionId)
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(QuizQuestionAnswer::getAnswerSelection, Collectors.counting()));
    }
```

Is there a way to simplify this code and make it more elegant as the following portion is repeated in both if/else branches

```
quizResponses.stream()
            .flatMap(response -> response.getAnswersByQuestions().stream())
            .filter(answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getQuestionId() == questionId)
```

I have attempted moving the `isMultiSelection ? :` check within the `collect()` but that throws a compile time error

```
private Map<Integer, Long> getCountPerAnswerChoice(boolean isMultiSelectableQuiz, int questionId, List<QuizResponse> quizResponses) {
     return quizResponses.stream()
        .flatMap(response -> response.getAnswersByQuestions().stream())
        .filter(answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getQuestionId() == questionId)
        .collect(
            isMultiSelectableQuiz
                ? Collectors.groupingBy(
                    QuizQuestionAnswer::getAnswerSelection, Collectors.counting())
                : Collectors.flatMapping(
                    (QuizQuestionAnswer answerByQuestion) -> answerByQuestion.getAnswerSelectionsList().stream(),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(selection -> selection, Collectors.counting())));
    }
```

Comment: If you move the hook inside the `collect` call, you can get rid of the first four lines of duplication (from `quizResponses` down to `collect`).

Comment: I have tried that but there is compile error thrown in the collect() of `no suitable method found for collect`

Comment: It would be good if you could edit your question, to add what the code looked like _after_ your attempt.  It's possible you've done something like messing up the nesting of the parentheses.

Comment: `getAnswersByQuestions` needs a `()` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that the java compiler has difficulty inferring the type arguments as they flow from stream to collector. The only difference between your two use cases is the collector used. I would pull the collectors out into a separate method to return the appropriate collector for each case. This not only helps clean up the code, the return type of the method providing the collector clarifies the types, avoiding the error.

```
private Map<Integer, Long> getCountPerAnswerChoice(boolean isMultiSelectableQuiz,
        int questionId, List<QuizResponse> quizResponses) {
    return quizResponses.stream()
        .flatMap(response -> response.getAnswersByQuestions().stream())
        .filter(answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getQuestionId() == questionId)
        .collect(getCollectorForQuizType(isMultiSelectableQuiz));
}

private Collector<? super QuizQuestionAnswer, ?, Map<Integer, Long>> getCollectorForQuizType(
        boolean isMultiSelectableQuiz) {
    return isMultiSelectableQuiz
        ? Collectors.groupingBy(QuizQuestionAnswer::getAnswerSelection, Collectors.counting())
        : Collectors.flatMapping(
            answerByQuestion -> answerByQuestion.getAnswerSelectionsList().stream(),
            Collectors.groupingBy(selection -> selection, Collectors.counting()));
}
```

I would even consider breaking it down further, perhaps storing the collectors in fields and just returning one by name. It still looks too busy to me with the ternary in there. Or return one inside an if block, and if it falls through, return the other.

Comment: *consider breaking it down further* - If it's a frequent operation, defining these collectors as static fields is a good idea, another option is to wrap each of them with a method. Something like `return isMultiSelectableQuiz ? group() : flattenAndGroup();`